# Vue: Hand Over An Object To A Component For It To Use

Tags: vue.js

In my app I have a list component which I use inside another component. Currently, it looks something like this:

```
<script setup>
const seed = [
  {
    key: value,
    anotherKey: anotherValue,
  },
  // and so on...
];
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="element in seed" :key="element.key" :anotherKey="element.anotherKey">
  </ul>
</template>
```

My question is: Is it possible to somehow "hand over" an object inside the parent component which uses this list component instead of getting the object from within the list component's script tag?

Comment: You mean like [props?](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props)

Answer (score 2):

You can use provide in your parent component to pass an object to your child components.

ParentComponent.vue (Untested code)

```
<script setup>
const seed = [
  {
    key: value,
    anotherKey: anotherValue,
  },
  // and so on...
];

provide('seed', seed)
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<script setup>
const seed = inject('seed')
</script>


<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="element in seed" :key="element.key" :anotherKey="element.anotherKey">
  </ul>
</template>
```

You can read about provide in compositions.
https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html